# How to create tables in Google BigQuery & PostgreSQL DB and what are keys and constraints?

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, key, constraints

How to create tables in Google BigQuery & PostgreSQL DB and what are the constraints we can use in BigQuery but not in postgreSQL?

Answer (score -1):

CREATE TABLE "TABLE_NAME"
(
"Column 1" "data type for column 1"  [column 1 constraints(s)],
"column 2" "data type for column 2"  [column 2 constraints(s)],
...
"Column n"
[tabe constraint(s)]
);

Table name will flow the <project_name>.<DB_Name>.<table_name> syntex

---

**NOTE: IN GOOGLE BIG QUERY WE DO NOT HAVE CONSTRAINTS LIKE PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY, AND UNIQUE KEY, BUT IN PostgreSQL WE CAN USE THEM.**

---

**Constraints:**

- **NOT NULL** Constraint: Ensures that a column cannot have a NULL value.
- **DEFAULT** Constraint: Provides a default value for a column when none is specified.
- **UNIQUE** Constraint: Make sure that all values in a column are different.
- **CHECK** Constraint: Makes sure that all values in a column satisfy certain criteria.
- **Primary Key** Constraint: Used to uniquely identify a row in the table.
- **Foreign Key** Constraint: Used to ensure referential integrity of the data.

**Keys:**

- A primary key is used to uniquely identify each row in a table.
- A primary key can consist of one or more columns on a table.
- When multiple columns are used as a primary key, they are called
  composite keys.
- A foreign key is a column (or columns) that references a column (most
  often the primary key) of another table.
- The purpose of the foreign key is to ensure the referential integrity
  of the data.

> **create table Customer_tbl(
> cust_id int primary key identity,
> first_name varchar,
> last_name varchar,
> age int,
> email_id varchar,
> mbile_num varchar);**